# Realm mongo login in reactnative

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm

I am trying to login a user in realm mongo using the email and password with following code

```
const signIn = async (email, password) => {
const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password);
const x= await app.logIn(credentials);
console.log("please run!");
console.log(x);
};
```

However when i console log x I don't get anything also on the appservices dashboard it shows am  logged in
should it return something like an object with various properties? including a token?
Kindly help me understand

Comment: Naming the vars so they match what's returned would help. `await app.logIn(` returns a user and that user will have user properties so changing `x` to `user` would clarify the code. Also, the code does not include error handling - I would wrap the code in a try-catch block and then use the catch to output any errors. That may be revealing